# Lowest positive and least negative value among various columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset looking like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3), timeA=c(-10, NA, NA, -15, -10, -5), timeB=c(5, 100, -10, -10, -15, 5), timeC=c(1, 160, 17, -5, -5, 2))
```

Question 1:
I want to create a column giving me the **lowest positive** value of **time** for each participant or if all values are negative then keep the negative value in and choose the one that is **least** **negative**. Then I want to only choose the lowest positive value for each participant (ID), or when all values are negative, choose the value that is least negative.

Question 2: Is there a function looking for the value that is closest to 0?

So that my output would look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3), time_new=c(1, -5, 2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply calculate distance to 0 and then `filter`

For #1

```
library(tidyverse)

# function filter check and return a TRUE/FALSE with
# follow logic of #1 - priority positive value first
# if no positive take the maximum negative number
filter_function <- function(x) {
  result <- rep(0, length(x))
  if (all(x < 0, na.rm = TRUE)) {
    reference <- max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  } else {
    reference <- min(x[x > 0], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
  result <- result + (x == reference)
  result[is.na(result)] <- 0
  
  as.logical(result)
}

# filter as #1 option
df %>% pivot_longer(!ID,values_to = "value") %>% 
  # calculate the distance to ZERO for each value
  mutate(distance_to_zero = 0 + value,
    abs_distance_to_zero = abs(distance_to_zero)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(filter_function(distance_to_zero))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>      ID name  value distance_to_zero abs_distance_to_zero
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>            <dbl>                <dbl>
#> 1     1 timeC     1                1                    1
#> 2     2 timeC    -5               -5                    5
#> 3     3 timeC     2                2                    2
```

And this is for #2

```
# filter as closest to ZERO no matter positive or negative
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!ID,values_to = "value") %>% 
  # calculate the distance to ZERO for each value
  mutate(abs_distance_to_zero = abs(0 + value)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  # Then filter by the one equal to minimum in each group can return multiple
  # records in your actual data
  filter(abs_distance_to_zero == min(abs_distance_to_zero, na.rm = TRUE) &
          !is.na(abs_distance_to_zero)) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      ID name  value abs_distance_to_zero
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>                <dbl>
#> 1     1 timeC     1                    1
#> 2     2 timeC    -5                    5
#> 3     3 timeC     2                    2
```

Comment: Wow! What a great solution, thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

I think your looking for `Closest()` from the library `DescTools`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DescTools)

# your data
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3), 
                 timeA=c(-10, NA, NA, -15, -10, -5), 
                 timeB=c(5, 100, -10, -10, -15, 5), 
                 timeC=c(1, 160, 17, -5, -5, 2))

# your results
# I stacked the information for easier searching
df %>% pivot_longer(!ID,values_to = "value") %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(time_new = Closest(value, 0, na.rm = T)) # closest value to zero
```